# new to Arrays and i'm stumped on logic

Tags: java

very basic method to grab the minimum value in an array WITHOUT using lists or Collections, etc, just but iterating

In my main driver i passed it three tests so far,

1. {2} - will print PASS if returned : 2
2. {1, 3, 8} - will print PASS if returned : 1
3. {9, 5, 8, 4} - will print PASS if returned : 4

the problem is when it gets to test 3 i get an

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 9
```

i know what this means, that my array is getting a number that is outside of my conditions but after sifting through i just can't pinpoint where.

```
 public int min(int[] newArray)
    {
        int value = newArray[0];


        if (newArray.length >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < newArray.length; ++i)
            {
                if (newArray[i] < newArray[value])
                {
                    value = newArray[i];
                    System.out.println(newArray[i]);
                }
                /**else if (newArray[i] > newArray[value])
                {
                    value = newArray[value];
                }
                */
            }
        }
        else if (newArray.length < 2)
        {
            value = newArray[0];
        }

        return value;
    }
```

JUST UPDATED MY CODE THUS FAR,

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP still having trouble though, have this all mapped on my whiteboard

Comment: `if (newArray[i] < newArray[value])` what is the content of `value` before this line first executes? That's your problem

Comment: value before this line executes is set to the first element in the newArray[]? @Smac89

Comment: precisely and this is what is causing the execption

Comment: hm.. well, if newArray[i] is 5 and newArray[value] is 9 (in the case of test 3) why would this cause errors? the logic of 5 < 9 is sound @Smac89

Comment: You might not need any if statements.

Comment: You are still missing the point. `newArray[value]` is NOT 9. `value` is 9, `newArray[value]` does not exist because your array is size 4. Notice your exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 9`, notice the 9 there? That is telling you that you supplied index 9, but index 9 does not exist, hence the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception message is telling you that the index 9 is out of bounds. Ask yourself: where is the system getting the number 9 from?

Below is an answer to your little homework exercise, but first I can't resist a little programming language lecture...

In programming language theory, subroutines that return return a value are called *functions*, those that return no value are called *procedures*. You are writing a function.

Sometimes it is helpful to maintain a variable in your function which serves as the return value, as you are with your `int value`. When doing so, it is good practice to give that variable the same name as the function. Some languages enforce this, though Java does not. So take a look at the function below and convince yourself that it works.

The `count` variable prevents unnecessary and costly referencing of array.length. Also, if array.length is zero, then this function does not iterate on the loop, and simply returns the largest possible int. This may or may not be appropriate for your program, but what happens when the array has no elements is a matter you *must* consider. However, if you presume that your array can contain *any* possible `int` value (and if it can't then how do you handle it if you encounter those values in `array`?), then Integer.MAX_VALUE is the only correct return value. Oh, and I forgot to check for a `null` `array`. Edited:

```
public int min(int[] array) {
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

   if (array == null) return min;

   const int count = array.length;
   for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
      min = min < array[i] ? min : array[i];
   }

   return min;
}
```

Comment: please don't resist the programming lecture! i love it haha, i'm in no means looking for a plain answer. My java prof is very hard to understand in class and so i look for extra help here understanding some things, thank you very much for explaining this to me i appreciate it @QED

Answer (score 1):

The problem is near the beginning.

```
if (newArray.length < 1)   //for the first test case, will just return [0] since the length of it is only 1 element, which has to be the min
{
    value = newArray[0];
}
```

If the length is less than 1, then it must be 0, meaning it is empty.  If the array is empty, you attempt to extract the first element.

You need to ask yourself: if the array is empty, what *is* the smallest number in it?  This is not a coding or algorithm question.  It's a design question.

Comment: oh crap i was thinking of it in terms of like an element, as in how it starts at 0 instead of 1 silly me the length is still 1 or 0(empty)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to tell you where the problem is.  That is your job ... and it is your job to learn how to do it.

This skill is called "debugging", and >>you<< need to learn how to do it.

However I am going to give you some suggestions as to how to find problems like this:

1. Learn to use your Java IDE's debugger.  It will include the capability to set breakpoints, single-step execute the program, and examine the state of objects and variables.
2. Use traceprints.  Temporarily add extra statements to your code to print out the values of variables.
3. Hand execution.  (This is really "old-school"<sup>1</sup>).  Get a paper and pencil and write down the names of the variables.  When pretend that you are the computer, and carefully "execute" the program by stepping through the statements and writing / updating the values of the variables on your piece of paper.

But in all cases, you need to learn to *think* about what your program *as written* does, and interpret the evidence that you are seeing.

---

<sup>1 - Don't laugh.  This was how they taught us to debug programs in the days when you wrote them on punched cards ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If the array length < 1 it is zero, so in that case it wall always cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 0

Also, you are saving the value of the array then using the value as an index to test against other array values.

either save the index of the value (value = i) and then return newArray[value] at the end or else save the value and test against the value itself (newArray[i] < value and newArray[i] > value)

Also, why use 2 if statments?

```
if (newArray.length == 0) return 0 (or whatever makes sense for your program).

int value = Integer.MAX_VALUE

for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    if (newArray[i] < value) {
        value = newArray[i];
    }
}

return value
```

Answer (score 0):

well, after all the advice i changed the method to the following

```
public int min(int[] newArray)
    {
        int value = newArray[0];


        if (newArray.length >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < newArray.length; ++i)
            {
                if (newArray[i] < value)
                {
                    value = newArray[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else if (newArray.length < 2)
        {
            value = newArray[0];
        }

        return value;
    }
```

this worked flawlessly for all 5 of my unique test cases, not one of them being an empty array though.. i suppose if i wanted to test that i would make an else statement saying if its empty than to return Invalid

Thanks everyone